# I use Hystrix(1.5.18) ,and set param ErrorThresholdPercentage=30,the circuitbreak status switch when marksuccess always

Tags: java, hystrix

I use hystrix(1.5.18) set `ErrorThresholdPercentage` equals 30, when the error percentage over the threshold, `circuitBreak` is open.

But, when an ahead request is return success, it will call `marksuccess` method to set `circuitBreak` false.

It is like a loop to switch the `circuitBreak` status.

Is this a bug in hystrix?

```
.withCircuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage(30)
.withCircuitBreakerSleepWindowInMilliseconds(2000)
```

I expect consumer will try request after 2000ms, but not soon after one ahead request is return success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you misunderstand the meaning of the property `circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds`.

If the circuit is opened, all your requests will be rejected **during `sleepWindowInMilliseconds`**. After `sleepWindowInMilliseconds` milliseconds elapse, it will become `half-open` state. In this state, only one request will be allowed and if it succeeds, the circuit will be closed again.

I guess that you saw the situation that your request was successful in `half-open` state and it closed the circuit.

The below diagram from the official wiki could help you understand.
[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer,i get the reason.
the version 1.5.18 on web https://mvnrepository.com has some question.method marksuccess is not the latest,it has not check the half-on status.i change the version to 1.5.12 solove the question.
thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/commit/c9241ac1a432a3c4eaef3d83a76bf2ccf73c9342